# Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, sails.js, bluebird

I am using bluebird and sails to build my application. When I use a database call inside the promise, it show me the warning like

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from
>   it

```
var P = require('bluebird');
return new P(function (resolve, reject) {
  Product.find({
    or: [
      {barcode: {'contains': q}},
      {name: {'contains': q}},
      {registrationCode: {'contains': q}}
    ]
  })
  .populate('batches')
  .exec(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    return resolve(products);
  });
}); //- end promise
```

Comment: Doesn't Sails already return promises? If so, you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

```js
//add return
return Product.find({
...
//wrapping inside bluebird promise wrapper is unnecessary here as well
```

> ...This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise of having a value at some point in the future.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [standard](https://promisesaplus.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
return Product.find({
    or: [
      {barcode: {'contains': q}},
      {name: {'contains': q}},
      {registrationCode: {'contains': q}}
    ]
  })
  .populate('batches')
  .exec().then(function(products) {
      //  your processing here
  });
```

`.exec()` already creates a promise, so you can just return that promise without wrapping it in another promise.

The warning you saw was because you weren't doing anything with a promise that was created inside an existing promise handler.  Without seeing more code, we can't say for sure if the warning was caused by you ignoring the promise that `.exec()` returns or if you aren't actually doing anything with the promise that this function returns.

See the Bluebird explanation for that warning [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it).  That makes it sound likely that the issue is that you were ignoring the promise returned by `.exec()`.

Comment: I have some processing in the exec(), and this function is a service, which will be called by other methods. So I should do something in the exec()

Comment: @Dzanvu -  `.exec()` returns a promise.  If you're using promises, you can do the processing in a `.then()` handler added to the promise that is returned from `.exec()`.  I added an example of that to the code in my answer.

Comment: you mean that if this function is called `AService.f`, and '// your processing here' is replaced by `return {a: 1, b: 2}`, I can get the object of `{a: 1, b: 2}` in another model action called `AController.g` via `AService.f(paramsPassed).then(function (obj) { console.log(obj); })`? As a result, the console.log can print `{a: 1, b: 2}`